# Submit button Form Data value not sent in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html

Submit value is sent in Safari but not Chrome

I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I have a very simple form that submits and calls some .php via a XMLHttpRequest in javascript. Safari is my main browser so everything was working fine. I would submit the form which would run my php script which insert a journal record into a MySQL database.

It's funny because I asked a friend to [check it out](http://142.68.36.50) and of course he tried it in Chrome which didn't work.

I'm sure it's something very silly.

I checked the network in the Chrome dev tools and it seems fine to me. No warnings or errors in the console.

The xhr.onload executed, but the xhr.responseText is an empty string.

[Chrome Network Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TXMb.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Daily Journal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body style="margin:10px;">
    <h1>Record your daily journal for review</h1>

    <form action="/journalInsert.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName">Your name</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" aria-describedby="userNameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
            <small id="userNameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Full name so we know who you are</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="notes">Record your daily journal</label>
            <textarea required class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" aria-describedby="notesHelp" placeholder="Journal entry for the day"></textarea>
            <small id="notesHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Be verbose, and break down your day. Let us know how many hours you worked on each task. Include any links used for research so that management has a clear idea on what's being developed.</small>
        </div>
        <button type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- blank modal template -->
    <div id="responseModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- the .setContent() method will update this element's HTML -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap.native/2.0.15/bootstrap-native-v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        var responseModal = document.getElementById('responseModal');
        var titleSubstitution = '[[TITLE]]';
        var bodySubstitution = '[[BODY]]';
        var responseModalBodyTemplate = ''
            + '<div class="modal-header">'
            + ' <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">' + titleSubstitution + '</h5>'
            + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">'
            + '  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
            + ' </button>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="modal-body">' + bodySubstitution + '</div>'
            + '<div class="modal-footer">'
            + ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'
            + '</div>';

        var responseModalInstance = new Modal(responseModal, {
            content: responseModalBodyTemplate,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: true
        });

        function showModal(title, body) {
            responseModalInstance.setContent(responseModalBodyTemplate
                .replace(titleSubstitution, title)
                .replace(bodySubstitution, body)
            );
            responseModalInstance.show();
        }

        function submitForm(form) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                // success case
                showModal('Success', xhr.responseText + ' ' + form.userName.value);
                form.notes.value = "";
            }
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                showModal('Error', xhr.responseText);
            }
            xhr.open (form.method, form.action, true);
            xhr.send (new FormData (form));

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your friend test it? You send him the HTML document and he opens it in Chrome? Or access the page directly from your server?

Comment: In the Chrome _Network_ console, click the AJAX request and look at the response. What does it look like?

Comment: Also, your `<script>` tag should be either inside the `<body>` or inside the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I just edited my html. I ran it through the https://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: @kennyzx - I made an apache2 web-server at home on ubuntu 14, I suppose I could of added the live link in my post. http://142.68.36.50/

Comment: @GabrielGates Confirm it is working in my test on Safari. But from the screen capture, the php being requested is on localhost. So your friend is requesting a nonexistent php?

Comment: @Phil I checked the Network console, should I look at anything in particular? Status Code is 200 OK, The Request Payload also looks fine.

Comment: @kennyzx - Your name is Erikfj, and you're recorded note was Dhdhdbdn

Comment: @kennyzx screenshot is indeed from my localhost. I got tired of pushing changes up to my web-server, so I created an apache2 setup using docker to test my changes locally instead.

Comment: What about the response body?

Comment: @Phil when I click the Response tab in chrome dev tools it displays "This request has no response data available." Under the Response Headers section is the following:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 12:23:32 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a closer look at the Request Payload betwen Safari and Chrome I noticed a difference between the two...

For Chrome:

> ------WebKitFormBoundarywCefymCztLxJ2hO0
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"
>
> Chrome
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarywCefymCztLxJ2hO0
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notes"
>
> TEST
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarywCefymCztLxJ2hO0--

For Safari:

> ------WebKitFormBoundarysw6ByLvitbY94DeC
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"
>
> Safari
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarysw6ByLvitbY94DeC
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notes"
>
> TEST
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarysw6ByLvitbY94DeC
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"
>
> Submit
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarysw6ByLvitbY94DeC--

My PHP script was validating whether the submit value, was being passed through. I guess Chrome will not pass through a button with type/value attributes set.

```html
<button type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Thanks everyone for the suggestions to my question, I'm happy it was something silly.

Answer (score 0):

With Safari 16.0 the FormData behaviour is changed, now in Safari also the value of the button clicked is not included as an entry of FormData object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16-release-notes

but before version 16 safari add the clicked button to the entries of  a FormData.